# py2app error on opening *.app, but not on Show Package Contents

Tags: python, py2app

This is the console output. I couldn't make sense out of it.

```
error   10:10:07.527514 +0700   Console Detected missing constraints for <private>.  It cannot be placed because there are not enough constraints to fully define the size and origin. Add the missing constraints, or set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=YES and constraints will be generated for you. If this view is laid out manually on macOS 10.12 and later, you may choose to not call [super layout] from your override. Set a breakpoint on DETECTED_MISSING_CONSTRAINTS to debug. This error will only be logged once.
```

This is the setup.py

```
APP = ['main.py']
DATA_FILES = [
    ('database',['database/HSK.xlsx', 'database/JLPT.xlsx']), 'config.txt'
]
OPTIONS = {
    'includes': 'openpyxl',
    'plist': {
        'CFBundleName': 'Duendecat'
    }
}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app','PyQt5','openpyxl'],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

try to reinstall py2app of version 0.13

```
pip install py2app==0.13
```

this works for me.
Seems version 0.14 has a bug

Comment: Actually, there seems to be a conflict between Openpyxl and Py2app.

Comment: @Polv I didn't even include any packages. This bug still exists.

Comment: As of now, the said conflict if already fixed with `openpyxl==2.3.5`. Also, `open -a dist/MyApplication.app` works, but not on double click.